# multiple javascript driven image Galleries on one page

Tags: javascript

I did a jquery tutorial from lynda.com to set up a java driven (css formatted) image gallery with neat effects and light box. It works fine.

I now want to create several galleries one one page and have each one only able to display the images associated with it. The problem is because the tags/IDs are all the same every gallery displays the same image. (for an example of the problem, please see... http://www.chartoonz.com/portfolio/illustration.html) As you can see the basic functionality works.

How can I get the java script to restrict functionality of one gallery to that gallery and leave the others alone? I thought, since the the jquery is doing the $(document).ready that it would happen at render time and so if I could loop it it would only do one gallery at a time, but that only accounts for the onload preview image. How can I seperate the galleries so that they don't all do the same thing no matter which thumbnail image is pressed? Can I?

As I said I thought I could loop it but I am having trouble with that! I tried taking all gallery_content tags into an array and then looping through the array, but I am clearly not doing that right as it didn't work.

I hope I have clearly articulated the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my pertinent javascript...

```
// What to do when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function(){


// Capture the thumbnail links

$('.gallery_thumbnails a').click(function(e){



// Disable standard link behavior

e.preventDefault();


// Fade out thumbnails
// Commented out to be in their own function (/**/)
/*
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').removeClass('selected');
$('.gallery_thumbnails a').children().css('opacity', '1');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$(this).children().css('opacity', '.4');
*/

// Add variables to link thumbnail to preview
var photo_caption = $(this).attr('title');
var photo_fullsize = $(this).attr('href');
var photo_preview = photo_fullsize.replace('_fullsize', '_preview');


$('.gallery_caption').slideUp(500);
$('.gallery_preview').fadeOut(500, function(){

// preload
$('.gallery_preload_area').html('<img src="'+photo_preview+'"/>');
$('.gallery_preload_area img').imgpreload(function(){

// Write the HTML into the page
$('.gallery_preview').html('<a class="overlaylink" href="'+photo_fullsize+'"       
title="'+photo_caption+'" style="background-image:url('+photo_preview+');"></a>');

// Update the html for the gallery caption
$('.gallery_caption').html('<p><a class="overlaylink zoom" href="'+photo_fullsize+'"     
title="'+photo_caption+'">View larger</a></p><p>'+photo_caption+'</p>')

$('.gallery_preview').fadeIn(500);
$('.gallery_caption').slideDown(500);

setFancyboxLinks();
updateThumbnails();

});

});

}

// Initialize the gallery on load
var first_photo_caption = $('.gallery_thumbnails a').first().attr('title');
var first_photo_fullsize =$('.gallery_thumbnails a').first().attr('href');
var first_photo_preview = first_photo_fullsize.replace('_fullsize', '_preview');

$('.gallery_caption').slideUp(500);
$('.gallery_preview').fadeOut(500, function(){

// preload
$('.gallery_preload_area').html('<img src="'+first_photo_preview+'"/>');
$('.gallery_preload_area img').imgpreload(function(){

// Write the HTML into the page
$('.gallery_preview').html('<a class="overlaylink" href="'+first_photo_fullsize+'" title= 
"'+first_photo_caption+'" style="background-image:url('+first_photo_preview+');"></a>');

// Update the html for the gallery caption
$('.gallery_caption').html('<p><a class="overlaylink zoom" href="'+first_photo_fullsize+'" 
title="'+first_photo_caption+'">View larger</a></p><p>'+first_photo_caption+'</p>')

$('.gallery_preview').fadeIn(500);
$('.gallery_caption').slideDown(500);

setFancyboxLinks();
updateThumbnails();

});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use more ids in your jQuery selectors, you can be more specific about the elements you are targeting and your code will run faster in most browsers :-)

try adding an id to each "galleryBodyWrapper" div like this:

```
div class="galleryBodyWrapper" id="gallery1">...
```

then you can write seperate selectors for each of your galleries like this:

```
$('#gallery1 .gallery_thumbnails').click(function(e){...
```

Of course, you will have to write out the code once for each gallery you are using. a neater way to do it would be to package the gallery code as an reusable object and pass the jQuery selectors into its constructor.

```
  chartoonz.ui.initGalleries('div.galleryBodyWrapper');
```

The init method would look something like this:

```
    /**
     * Create a gallery object for each div on this page that matches the selector
     *
     * @return void
     */
    initGalleries:function(selector){
        chartoonz.$(selector).each(
            function(intIndex,domEle){
                var galleryDiv = chartoonz.$(domEle);
                chartoonz.ui.galleries[intIndex] = new chartoonz.ui.gallery(galleryDiv);
            });
```

```
},
```

so you could refactor your original code like this (I have briefly tested it, and it seems to work with your HTML)

```
//Set up a page namespace
chartoonz = {};
//localise the jQuery object to prevent conflicts
chartoonz.$ = jQuery;

/**
 * Object to contain page UI elements and interactions
 *
 */
chartoonz.ui={
    /**
     * Container for all chartoonz.ui.gallery objects on this page.
     * @var Array 
     */
    galleries:[],


    /**
     * Create a gallery object for each div on this page that matches the selector
     *
     * @return void
     */
    initGalleries:function(selector){

        chartoonz.$(selector).each(
                                   function(intIndex,domEle){
                                       var galleryDiv = chartoonz.$(domEle);
                                       chartoonz.ui.galleries[intIndex] = new chartoonz.ui.gallery(galleryDiv);
                                   });

    },


    /**
     * The gallery object
     */
    gallery:function(context){
        /**
         * container for all of the thumbnails in this gallery
         * @var Array
         */
        this.thumbnails = [];
        /**
         * The caption div for this gallery.
         * @var jQuery
         */
        this.captionEle = chartoonz.$('.gallery_caption',context);
        /**
         * The preview div for this gallery.
         * @var jQuery
         */
        this.previewEle = chartoonz.$('.gallery_preview',context);
        /**
         * The pre-load div for this gallery.
         * @var jQuery
         */
        this.preloadEle = chartoonz.$('.gallery_preload_area',context);
        /**
         * The pre-load image for this gallery.
         * @var jQuery
         */
        this.preloadEleImg = chartoonz.$('img',this.preloadEle);

        //initialise the thumbnails
        var parentGallery = this;
        chartoonz.$('a',context).each(
                                      function(intIndex,domEle){
                                          var obj = chartoonz.$(domEle);

                                          obj.click(function(e){
                                                    // Disable standard link behavior
                                                    e.preventDefault();

                                                    // Add variables to link thumbnail to preview
                                                    var photo_caption = obj.attr('title');
                                                    var photo_fullsize = obj.attr('href');
                                                    var photo_preview = photo_fullsize.replace('_fullsize', '_preview');

                                                    parentGallery.setMain(photo_caption,photo_fullsize,photo_preview);

                                                    });
                                          parentGallery.thumbnails[intIndex] = obj; 

                                      });

        /**
         * Update the html for the  gallery caption
         *
         * @return void
         */
        this.setCaption = function(photo_caption,photo_fullsize){

            this.captionEle.html('<p><a class="overlaylink zoom" href="'+photo_fullsize+'" title="'+photo_caption+'">View larger</a></p><p>'+photo_caption+'</p>')

        }


        /**
         * Set the  html for the preview
         *
         * @return void
         */
        this.setPreview = function(photo_caption,photo_fullsize,photo_preview){

            this.previewEle.html('<a class="overlaylink" href="'+photo_fullsize+'" title= "'+photo_caption+'" style="background-image:url('+photo_preview+');"></a>');  

        }


        /**
         * Set the  main image
         *
         * @return void
         */
        this.setMain = function(photo_caption,photo_fullsize,photo_preview){

            this.captionEle.slideUp(500);
            var parentGallery = this;
            this.previewEle.fadeOut(500, function(){

                                    // preload
                                    parentGallery.preloadEle.html('<img src="'+photo_preview+'"/>');
                                    parentGallery.preloadEleImg.imgpreload(function(){

                                                                           parentGallery.setPreview(photo_caption,photo_fullsize,photo_preview);
                                                                           parentGallery.setCaption(photo_caption,photo_fullsize);

                                                                           parentGallery.previewEle.fadeIn(500);
                                                                           parentGallery.captionEle.slideDown(500);

                                                                           setFancyboxLinks();
                                                                           updateThumbnails();


                                                                           });




                                    });

        }

        //  Initialize the gallery on load
        var first_photo_caption = this.thumbnails[0].attr('title');
        var first_photo_fullsize =this.thumbnails[0].attr('href');
        var first_photo_preview = first_photo_fullsize.replace('_fullsize', '_preview');
        this.setMain(first_photo_caption,first_photo_fullsize,first_photo_preview);   

    }


};


$(document).ready(function(){
                  // Navigation Menu
                  navWrapper();
                  //footerText();
                  followLogos();
                  calculateDate();

                  //This line sets up the galleries
                  chartoonz.ui.initGalleries('div.galleryBodyWrapper');

                  });


// Functions... Your other functions go here as before.
```

Hope that helps

_Pez

Comment: try adding an id to each "galleryBodyWrapper" div like this:

div class="galleryBodyWrapper" id="gallery1">...

then you can write seperate selectors for each of your galleries like this:

$('#gallery1 .gallery_thumbnails').click(function(e){...

Of course, you will have to write out the code once for each gallery you are using. a neater way to do it would be to package the gallery code as an reusable object and pass the jQuery selectors into its constructor.
How do I do that?  I'm new at this...

Comment: BTW I am hoping to not have to hard code repetitious functionality.  The goal is to drive the gallery functionality locally whilst simultaneously being able to handle an arbitrary number of galleries.  I wish I could solve this.  
I tried the ID tag and tried creating an array that would find the various IDs but you cannot throw wildcards in getElementById.  I've also been looking at jquery... I'm hardly an expert with that but so far nothings working...  any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't specify that you wanted to avoid code-reuse in the original question. I have modified my answer.